# flickering issue on uitableview scroll when setting custom cell attributes by dispatch asynchrony

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

i have a uitableview  with custom cell.Custom cell contain some fields like label.I use dispatch_async to get data from time consuming process and then update cell attributes in main.However i face flickering of custom cell data on scrolling.The code i have:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

OpenOrdersCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIndetifier"];
LanguageModule *langModule=[LanguageModule sharedModule];

if (!cell) {
    UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OpenOrdersCell" bundle:nil];
    cell = (OpenOrdersCell *)controller.view;

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:238.0f/255.0f green:238.0f/255.0f blue:238.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
}

Order *order = [self.arrayOfOpenOrders objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, NULL), ^
               {
                   NSString *str = [langModule getLocalizedString:@"Select"];

                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^

                                  {
                                      [cell.detailButton setTitle:str forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                                      cell.detailButton.tag = indexPath.row + 1;
                                      [cell.detailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(detailButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                                  });

               });

if ([order.mStatus intValue] == 0)//called from closed order class
{
//        [cell.sendInvoiceButton setTitle:[langModule getLocalizedString:@"Reorder"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, NULL), ^
    {
        NSString *str = [langModule getLocalizedString:@"Send Receipt"];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^

        {
            [cell.sendInvoiceButton setTitle:str forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            cell.sendInvoiceButton.tag = indexPath.row + 1;
            [cell.sendInvoiceButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sendInvoiceButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            CGFloat x = cell.detailButton.frame.origin.x;//original x
            if ([Utils getSendInvoiceOption] == FALSE) {

                [cell.sendInvoiceButton setHidden:YES];
                cell.detailButton.frame = CGRectMake(cell.sendInvoiceButton.frame.origin.x+30, cell.detailButton.frame.origin.y, cell.detailButton.frame.size.width, cell.detailButton.frame.size.height);
            }
            else
            {
                cell.detailButton.frame = CGRectMake(x, cell.detailButton.frame.origin.y, cell.detailButton.frame.size.width, cell.detailButton.frame.size.height);
                [cell.sendInvoiceButton setHidden:NO];
            }
        });

    });



}





dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, NULL), ^
{
    NSString *str = [langModule getLocalizedString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",order.mDateTime]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^

                   {
                       cell.dateTimeLabel.text = str;
                   });

});



dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, NULL), ^
{
    NSString *str = [langModule getLocalizedString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",order.mOrderId]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^

                   {
                       cell.orderIdLabel.text = str;

                   });

});

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, NULL), ^
               {
                   NSString *str = [langModule getLocalizedString:order.mTotalItems];
                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^

                    {
                        cell.totalItemsLabel.text = str;

                    });

               });



dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, NULL), ^
{
    NSString *str = [Utils currencyWithSymbol:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", [order.mTotalAmount floatValue]]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^

                   {
                       cell.totalAmountLabel.text  = str;
                   });

});




dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, NULL), ^
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^

                   {

                   });

});





if (IndexPath && IndexPath.row == indexPath.row)
{
    [cell.contentView addSubview:expandedCellView];
}

cell.contentView.tag = indexPath.row + 1;

return cell;
}
```

if some can suggest me, how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I think you're using far too many blocks for very simple operations.  Also, you're doing a lot of configuration of cells within this method when it is probably easier to just use different cells to display different things. e.g, you're changing the heights of the cells within the method, but are you also implementing `heightForCellAtIndexPath:` to return the same height?

Comment: Thanks for interset, i have test my cell for row at index path using time profiler.Previously i was using cell.whateverLabel.text = [langModule getLocalizedString:order.mTotalItems];, this was taking too much of time thats why i use dispatch_async.......Also all cell are of same ui, so  why should i use diffenet cell?  Yes i am using heightForCellAtIndex....which comes into significance at time of collapse/expand